# Sitecore PowerShell Extensions get descendant of an item using a template

Tags: powershell-extensions

I'm writing an SPE script and am looping over my site nodes. For each site node, I want to check if a particular descendant exists and if not then create it. I have the list of top-level nodes, but cannot figure out how to query each of those nodes for a descendant.

If I was writing in regular query syntax, I could write something like this:

```
var sites = database.SelectItems("fast:/sitecore/content/Master/*[@@templatename='Website']");
foreach (var site in sites)
{
    var settingsItem = site.Axes.SelectItem("descendant::*[@@templatename='Settings']");
    //now check if SettingsItem is null, if so create etc
}
```

What I have in my SPE script:

```
#get the list of top-level site nodes
$sites = Get-Item master: -Query "fast:/sitecore/content/Master//*[@@templatename='Website']";
foreach ($site in $sites)
{
    # get descendant of each $site item that inherits from "Settings" template 
    $settings = ???
    if ($settings == null) {
        #create settings item etc...
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, `$site` will be of the type `Sitecore.Data.Items.BaseItem`, so it has all the standard API available.

You can achieve the desired behavior like this:

```
$settings =
    $site.Axes.GetDescendants() |
        ? { $_.TemplateName -eq "Settings" } |
        select -first 1

if($settings -eq $null) {
    # create settings etc
}
```

If performance is important for you, you can use [**Fast Query**](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/developer/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query001.pdf):

```
$query = "fast:" + $site.Paths.Path + "//*[@@templateid='{your-template-id-here}']"

$settings = Get-Item master: -Query $query | select -first 1
```

Note that I used the ID of the template instead of its name. This reduces the need for SQL joins and makes the query much faster.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about calling methods like that. $site.Axes.GetDescendants() will be a bit of a killer though won't it.. Presume I could also do $site.Axes.SelectSingleItem() right?

Comment: @MatthewDresser Your original `SelectSingleItem` query will perform exactly the same as `GetDescendants`. See my updated answer for a faster solution.

Comment: ah ok, thanks for that, I didn't know about that. Thanks for the updated solution. Out of interest, if the site item (or one of its ancestors) was named with a space or underscore or hyphen, would that query still work, or would I need to escape it manually?

Comment: @MatthewDresser It would work even with whitespaces, underscores and hyphens, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this snippet.

```powershell
# get descendant of each $site item that inherits from "Settings" template 
# $site = gi .
$settingsBase = "{6669DC16-F106-44B5-96BE-7A31AE82B5B5}"
$settingItems= Get-ChildItem -Path $site.Paths.Path | Where-Object { 
    [Sitecore.Data.Managers.TemplateManager]::GetTemplate($_).InheritsFrom($settingsBase) 
}
```

`$settingsBase` is a base settings template **ID** or base settings template **Name**.

Be careful. If you have multiple settings it will return an array, so select single (first element) you can use
`$settingItems | select -First 1`

Comment: I just need to find descendants of the site item based on my "Settings" template.

Comment: Isn't my code doing that? (removed  `-Recurse` switch)

Comment: Apologies, my question was badly worded, it should have said "...of an item using a template"

Comment: No worries. I am glad you've got a solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dmytro Shevchenko's answer did what was needed, but the `Axes.GetDescendants()` call will, as the name suggests, retrieve all items which is a pretty expensive operation. The code below seems to work ok:

```
$settings = $site.Axes.SelectSingleItem("descendant::*[@@templatename='Settings']")
```

Comment: It doesn't meet that criteria: "get a descendant of an item **inheriting** from a template", which is important if your solution must work on instances where somebody wants to override Settings template.

Comment: Please note that, since your query is not a Fast Query, this solution will be equivalent to `.GetDescendants()`, i.e. it will iterate through each item's children recursively. If you really need good performance, you can try converting your query to a Fast Query. Keep in mind that `descendant::` won't work with Fast Query unless you change the value of the `FastQueryDescendantsDisabled` setting to `true` in the _Sitecore.config_.